# how html5 apache works first time

Tags: html, html5-appcache

I have created one HTML5 web app which works in offline mode.I load it first time form server and then when server is off it works perfectly.Webapp url is `http://localhost/index.html`

Now , if I try to load that webapp first time on  any new machine then how can it resolve the localhost url.I have all the resources bundled with webapp.

In this case server is off and browser is not able to locate url `http://localhost/index.html`

Any idea if webapp can work in offline mode , even if its not connected to server ever.

Comment: You still need your local server established to locate localhost url. How do you mean. Prospect of 'offline' web app is not what you think it is. It just means that you can save your data in lets say localStorage or something and then sync with server when you are online. http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

Comment: So is there a way to make it work if either local server is there or not?

Comment: Depends on your app. What features it has, where does it get data from etc. If you have most of your data from let's say JSON, you can definitely do this. If you get data from some API or from web then it gets tricky of course. Read on it on the link I provided

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing and expecting seems to make sense. It would be smart to check the console in the Chrome Developer tools. Something along the lines of the following should be shown:

[image]

You might be serving the manifest file with the wrong `content type` (should be `text/cache-manifest`) or the fact that you're working on `localhost` might somehow interfere (dunno).

Comment: In simple terms I have local web server ,when its running I can see my web app up and running and next time when web server is stopped I can see web contents served from appcache. This is perfectly fine. Now what will happen if I try to hit my website first time on my browser and server is down. My browser wont be able to locate url and it will fail with 404 error. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @Alien01: What do you mean as the difference between a stopped server and a server that's down?

Comment: Looks like I created some confusion here,actually I mean to say that for both server stopped and down it means server is not reachable.